# phpunit cant find eloquent class in laravel

Tags: laravel, tdd, phpunit, laravel-4

I am following the laravel testing decoded book and have gotten into a spot were I don't know what I have done wrong or how to fix it.

When I run phpunit I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found in C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\traine
rcompare\app\models\BaseModel.php on line 8
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bi
n\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpun
it\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:63
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpuni
t\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\v
endor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:138
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() C:\ProgramData\
Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:657
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\
vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Configuration.php:789
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin
\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Configuration.php:873
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\
vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:416
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin
\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:389
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\
vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:315
PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestMethod() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bi
n\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:212
PHP  12. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::createTest() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\v
endor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:834
PHP  13. UserControllerTest->__construct() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\ph
punit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:473
PHP  14. Mockery::mock() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercompare\app\tests\User
ControllerTest.php:7
PHP  15. call_user_func_array() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercompare\vendor\
mockery\mockery\library\Mockery.php:50
PHP  16. Mockery\Container->mock() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercompare\vend
or\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery.php:50
PHP  17. class_exists() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercompare\vendor\mockery\
mockery\library\Mockery\Container.php:120
PHP  18. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\tr
ainercompare\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Container.php:0
PHP  19. include() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:1
85

Fatal error: Class 'Eloquent' not found in C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercomp
are\app\models\BaseModel.php on line 8

Call Stack:
    0.0004     235376   1. {main}() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\p
hpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:0
    0.0044     545360   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\ProgramData\Compose
r\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:63
    0.0044     550584   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\ProgramData\Composer
\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
    0.0044     551016   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() C:\ProgramD
ata\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:138
    0.0163    1273880   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration
() C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php
:657
    0.0164    1274776   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() C:\Program
Data\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Configuration.php:789
    0.0264    1494488   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() C:\Progra
mData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Configuration.php:873
    0.0423    2883168   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() C:\Program
Data\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:416
    0.0435    2986944   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestSuite() C:\Progra
mData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:389
    0.0435    2987688  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->__construct() C:\Program
Data\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:315
    0.0437    3089088  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestMethod() C:\Progr
amData\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:212
    0.0438    3089504  12. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite::createTest() C:\ProgramD
ata\Composer\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:834
    0.0438    3096296  13. UserControllerTest->__construct() C:\ProgramData\Comp
oser\bin\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:473
    0.0449    3192368  14. Mockery::mock() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercomp
are\app\tests\UserControllerTest.php:7
    0.0462    3302320  15. call_user_func_array() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trai
nercompare\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery.php:50
    0.0462    3302720  16. Mockery\Container->mock() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\t
rainercompare\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery.php:50
    0.0462    3305216  17. class_exists() C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercompa
re\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Container.php:120
    0.0462    3305536  18. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\Users\M
ark\Dropbox\www\trainercompare\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Container.
php:0
    0.0465    3311464  19. include('C:\Users\Mark\Dropbox\www\trainercompare\app
\models\BaseModel.php') C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.
php:185
```

Now I have gotten as far as figuring out that it must be that phpunit is not getting the laravel app pre loaded so here is my phpunit.xml and composer.json which do the autoloading for me

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "machuga/authority-l4": "2.0.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev":{
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "way/laravel-test-helpers": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/tests/helpers"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
        <testsuite name="Unit Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/UnitTests</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Integration Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/IntegrationTests</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Functional Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/FunctionalTests</directory>
        </testsuite>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I am not using a setup function in test case so that is not the problem and here is the test I am trying to run

```
<?php
  use Way\Tests\Factory;

class UserTest extends TestCase {

    use ModelHelpers;

    public function testIsInvalidWithoutAnEmail()
    {
        $user = new User;

        $this->assertFalse($user->validate());
    }

}
```

On this class

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|min:4',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,16|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,8',
        'firstName' => 'required|alpha_num',
        'gender' => 'required|alpha',
        'dob' => 'required',
        'townCity' => 'required|alpha_num',
        'country' => 'required|alpha_num'
        );


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    ****snipped rest for spaces sake****

}
```

which extends this class, which extends eloquent which cant be found

attributes, static::$rules);

        if ($v->passes()) return true;

        $this->errors = $v->messages();

        return false;
    }
}
?>

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your BaseModel class. Did you include `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent` or something similar to extend `Eloquent`?

Comment: I just tried that and I seem to get a step further into the process than before.  Is there a reason why I would have to use that namespace all of a sudden?  It has always worked before without it.  It does seem to have occurred after I had added namespaces for something else to one of the test classes

Comment: I am ahppy to accept that as the answer as it worked even though I am not sure why I need to do that all of a sudden

Comment: Had the same problem using facades. But I could fix it by adding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` to the top of the file I was testing. Weird. Would love to know why!